# How to put www in front of my website?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3

How to put www in front of my website
now we are getting like https://vitalticks.in

if we enter www.vitalticks.in we are getting below error 
[image]

Comment: are you using nginx or apache? please share site-available conf settings as well. I think the issue is with your host configuration

Comment: Are you use wildcard ssl ?

Answer (score 0):

please try to add below code in .htaccess :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com
    RewriteRule (.*) http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

if you are using nginx than check with below url :

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/redirecting-non-www-to-www-in-nginx

**hope its work for you**

Answer (score 0):

> **DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN**
>
> is an error which indicates a non-existent domain. In other terms, 
>   the DNS cannot find the IP address corresponding to the domain name. 
>   Thus, users receive this error on Google Chrome and are unable to 
>   reach the website they are trying to access.

1. need to add DNS record for subdomain - `www`
2. change magento base url to `https://www.vitalticks.in/`
3. add redirect to `.htaccess`

   `RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]`